# Why did "Charlie Francis" appear in the Episode 11 of Season 2 of Fringe?

Tags: fringe, continuity

The character had been killed episodes before and appeared totally unexpectedly in the episode called [Unearthed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unearthed_(Fringe)). As the Wikipedia notes:

> Though his character Charlie Francis had been killed off earlier in the second season, former series regular Kirk Acevedo appeared in the episode, sparking confusion among some viewers.

Has this ever been properly explained?

Comment: That explanation doesn't really make sense considering the plot of the "unearthed" episode follows events that happened in S2E1. It sounds like they took some junk footage they discarded earlier and just slammed it into this episode with total disregard for how foolish it looked.

Comment: @user11887 What parts of the plot follow S2E1?

Comment: @Keen None that I recall.  He may be referring to the [press release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unearthed_(Fringe)#Production) that Fox added, which hinted that the episode may be set in an alternate universe.  That, however, is not part of the episode and is just Fox being stupid.

Comment: God... finally some closure :P

Comment: God. Thats rubbish.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Basically, it was an episode they made during the first season, but didn't air.  Fox decided to air it during the second season.

This was explained during its original airing.  The Fox promos for that episode explained it as a 'lost 1st season episode'.  That's why Charlie's there, and there's no attention drawn to his presence, as he was always around during season 1.

Also, in this scan of the blu-ray booklet, you could see that the *Unearthed* episode is within the special feature of the disk 4. So the episode number 11 is "Johari Window".

[image: blu-ray booklet]

Comment: Go Fox! </sarcasm>

Comment: Stupidity is always good thing. I mean they did not air it but who cares throw it in the second seasond. It all makes sense

Comment: When watching the series on (Dutch) Netflix, it's positioned between seasons 1 and 2. Which did make _some_ sense, regarding people coming back from apparent death and screaming gibberish. But it probably would have been better _before_ the final episode of the first season.

Comment: Explains Agent Farnsworth's hair as well. Thank you for explaining this, was going a bit nuts.

Comment: Sh*t, I had to repeat few episodes quickly to make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: they didn't even make a funeral for him. I thought that he came from an episode that was in another universe but I was wrong.

Comment: @ainasiart I also had to check back an episode. Lost episode is definitely an odd explanation.